# Heart rate monitor on a smartwatch

Tags: heart-rate, heart-rate-monitor

Does a smartwatch take into account heart rate when it computes calories burned?

I know there are a number of personal factors (Age, weight etc) that go into the equation, and of course your movement/steps but if you were to workout on a elliptical with your hands on the stationary handle bars would your fitness tracker compute  your calories burned from just your heart rate?

Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because product questions should be asked on the product's own forum.

Comment: @Alec - He isn't linking a specific product. I am very borderline on this question, I think there is a good core in there but haven't had time to recommend a fix or edit it.

Comment: @JohnP - But if he's not talking about a specific product, and instead the general idea of such a product, the answer will inevitably be "some yes, some no". I think the question "is this even possible?" is the interesting part. The title and first line are speculation, until someone answers a simple yes or no, which is going to come from each manufacturer anyway.